# netstandard.dll missing at GAC on fresh installation

Tags: msbuild, .net-standard, build-tools

I try to setup clean CI build agent with MSBuild support. I use [Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#other) and [component directory list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-build-tools)

```
Start-Process -Wait -PassThru -FilePath vs_BuildTools.exe -ArgumentList '--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreBuildTools \
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.WebBuildTools \
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools \
    --add Microsoft.Net.Component.4.5.1.TargetingPack \
    --add Microsoft.Net.Component.4.5.2.TargetingPack \
    --add Microsoft.Net.Component.4.5.TargetingPack \
    --add Microsoft.Net.Component.4.6.TargetingPack \
    --add Microsoft.Net.Component.4.TargetingPack \
    --add Microsoft.Net.ComponentGroup.TargetingPacks.Common \
    --add Microsoft.Net.Component.3.5.DeveloperTools \
    --add Microsoft.Net.Component.4.6.2.SDK \
    --add Microsoft.Net.Component.4.6.2.TargetingPack \
    --add Microsoft.Net.Component.4.7.1.SDK \
    --add Microsoft.Net.Component.4.7.1.TargetingPack \
    --add Microsoft.Net.Component.4.7.SDK \
    --add Microsoft.Net.Component.4.7.TargetingPack \
    --add Microsoft.Net.ComponentGroup.4.6.2.DeveloperTools \
    --add Microsoft.Net.ComponentGroup.4.7.1.DeveloperTools \
    --add Microsoft.Net.ComponentGroup.4.7.DeveloperTools \
    --quiet \
    --nocache \
    --wait'
```

*Code snippet is part of [Dockerfile](https://github.com/jincod/docker-jenkins-slave/blob/master/windows/Dockerfile#L14)

I expect *netstandard.dll* will be locate at GAC (*c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\netstandard*). Which package should I install additionally?

Comment: netstandard.dll will be in the GAC if the CI machine runs .NET Framework 4.7.1 or newer.

Comment: `--add Microsoft.Net.Component.4.7.1.SDK \` I've setup this component, but is doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've installed .NET Framework separately and it works now. [Full Dockerfile](https://github.com/jincod/docker-jenkins-slave/blob/4dd023bccf288ab416cd4f73bd25609116c1afa1/windows/Dockerfile#L11)

Answer (score 0):

netstandard.dll will be in the GAC if the machine runs .NET Framework 4.7.1 or newer, I've installed it and fixed my problems with "netstandard.dll"